# css make background image appear both at left and right of element

Tags: css, background-image

I have an unordered list in a navigation with a separator like so:

```
background: {url("images/navseperator.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent}
```

This works fine but I want to add the same image to the left something like so:

```
background: {url("images/navseperator.png") no-repeat scroll LEFT top transparent}
```

When I add this line the original separator on the right disappears and replaced by the one on the left only.

How would I add this background image to both the left and right hand sides of this element?

Comment: You can only set one background image by css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS2< only support one background image. but if you are using css3,

```
background: url("images/navseperator.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent, url("images/navseperator.png") no-repeat scroll LEFT top transparent;
```

for css2 ,

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="right">
        content here
    </div>
</div>

.left{
    background: url("images/navseperator.png") no-repeat scroll LEFT top transparent;
}
.right{
    background: url("images/navseperator.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent
}
```

Comment: Thanks this sounds promising but it does not seem to be working. Novice here... how do I "make" my css sheet css3?

Comment: That depends on your browser. Older internet browsers do not have support for CSS3. ie. If you develop your website with CSS3, visitor 1 might be able to see the two corners while me, using an older browser might not be able to see it

Comment: updated answer to support older browsers as well. you can select one of them

Comment: @Doug Firr: You don't "make" your stylesheet a certain version of CSS. If you're using a CSS2 feature, you're using a CSS2 feature. If you're using a CSS3 feature, you're using a CSS3 feature. It's as simple as that.